# Drupal : Flowplayer API not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, flowplayer

I have a little problem with the "Flowplayer API" module. I activated it in the modules list and in my node template I'm using the "flowplayer_add" function to embed my video/audio.

What is strange is that no css or js for Flowplayer is loaded...

Maybe you have this answer to that.

N.B. I've already tried to remove all the other js files to avoid conflicts but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

On [the help section](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer) they explain the difference between theme('flowplayer') and flowplayer_add():

> Calling theme('flowplayer') will not only add the correct JavaScript to the page, but also construct the markup for you.
>
> Using flowplayer_add requires you to already have the markup created.

i.e. in the case of flowplayer_add() you have to set HTML like this:

```
<a href="http://my-site.com/my-video.mp4" id="player"></a>
```

somewhere on the page, where you want your video to appear.

Hope it helps